# RecyclerView creates margins when scrolling sometimes

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

RecyclerView creates a margin that only comes out after scrolling up and down. This doesn't occur for all items but it always occur to the same item.

EDIT: margins I marked with black circles are bigger than the green ones. Its supposed to all have the same space between each items

[image: margins I marked with black circles are bigger than the green ones. Its supposed to all have the same space between each itesm]

and here is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context="com.mangolassi.norman.steller.MessageRoomActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="SEND"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the item xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/userAvatar"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/default_avatar"
            />

        <TextView
            style="@style/incomingMessage"
            android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
            android:text="bsp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        style="@style/outgoingMessage"
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView2"
        android:text="bsp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

im using the latest Android Studio

Comment: What margin are you talking about?

Comment: I added some notations to the screenshot. The spacing between each itemlist is not always the same.

Comment: Your item's `xml` seems to be invalid: `LinearLayout` tag never closes.

Comment: missed it while pasting. Fixed the xml on the question.